# playwright test website with Keycloak, can't find a way to logIn via pageObjectModel

Tags: javascript, pageobjects, playwright-test

Hi (i am pretty new in palywright),

I need/want to find a way in playwright, to login via pageObjectModel in a aplication which uses keycloak, but I don't know how.

I found a way without pageObject, to logIn in first test and saving the auth in process.env.STORAGE and then use test.use({storageState: auth_storage_path}) in the rest of the test inside the file.spec.js;

note: keycloak works (sorry for this basic info)

- user not login -> visit.baseUrl, redirects you to keycloak authPage
- user already logIn -> visit.baseUrl goes direct to bareUrl. (so no logIn button in homepage etc)

```
//tests_with_auth_store.spec.js

    const {test, expect}    = require('@playwright/test');
    const auth_storage_path = 'storage_auth.json';
    const baseUrl           = 'https://myBaseUrl_xyz.com';


    test('mylogin', async ({page, context}) => {
      const usernameId    = '[id="username"]';
      const passwordId    = '[id="password"]';
      const idLogin       = '[id="login-button"]';
      const usernameValue = '*****';
      const passwordValue = '*****';
    
      //login:
      await page.goto(baseUrl);
      await page.fill(usernameId, usernameValue);
      await page.fill(passwordId, passwordValue);
    
      await Promise.all([
        page.waitForNavigation(/*{ baseUrl: baseUrl }*/),
        page.click(idLogin)
      ]);
      process.env.STORAGE = null;
      const storage = await context.storageState({ path: auth_storage_path });
      process.env.STORAGE = JSON.stringify(storage);
      JSON.parse(process.env.STORAGE);
    
    });
    
    test.describe("testDescription login via pageObjectModel", () => {
    
      test.use({storageState: auth_storage_path});
    
      test('i- firstTest whatever ', async ({page}) => {
        await page.goto(baseUrl);
        ......
        ....
      });

      test('ii- secondTest whatever ', async ({page}) => {
        await page.goto(baseUrl);
        ......
        ....
      });
});
```

This works ok and all test under test.use({storageState: auth_storage_path});
can jump to baseUrl directly. The problem is that I can not find a way to encapsulate test('login') into a playwright pageObject (in cypress we did it in simple func in commands.js and saving the auth into cookies)

My demo for login-page.js:

```
// login-page.js
const { expect, test} = require('@playwright/test');
const baseUrl = 'https://myBaseUrl_xyz.com';
const auth_storage_path = 'storage_auth.json';

exports.LoginPage = class LoginPage {
  
  /**
   * @param {import('@playwright/test').Page} page
   */
  
  constructor(page) {
    this.page = page;
  }
  
   async login() {
     process.env.STORAGE = null;
     const baseUrl = 'https://myBaseUrl_xyz';

     await this.page.goto(baseUrl);
     await this.page.fill('[id="username"]', '*****');
     await this.page.fill('[id="password"]', '*****');

     await Promise.all([
      this.page.waitForNavigation(/*{ baseUrl: baseUrl }*/),
      this.page.click('[id="fc-login-button"]')
    ]);


     const storage = await this.page.context().storageState({path: auth_storage_path});
     process.env.STORAGE = JSON.stringify(storage);
     JSON.parse(process.env.STORAGE);
  }
  

  // async gotoBaseUrl() {
  //   test.use({storageState: auth_storage_path});
  //   return  this.page.goto(baseUrl);
  // }
  
}
```

call login-page from tests_with_auth_store_viaPage.spec.js

```
// tests_with_auth_store_viaPage.spec.js
const {test, expect} = require('@playwright/test');
const { LoginPage } = require('../login/login-page');
const auth_storage_path = 'storage_auth.json';

const baseUrl = 'https://myBaseUrl_xyz.com';

test('login', async ({page}) => {
  const loginPage = new LoginPage(page);
  await loginPage.login();
});

test.describe("testDEscription tests with save login into json", () => {

  test.use({storageState: auth_storage_path});

  test('i- firstTest whatever', async ({page}) => {
    await page.goto(baseUrl);
    ......
    ....
   });
```

But here test('i- firstTest whatever') page.goto(baseUrl) does NOT jump to baseUrl but to keycloak auth page :(.

Eventhoug test('login') is login and creating storage_auth.json. So I am doing something wrong maybe I need something like loginPage.gotoBaseUrl(), but it doesn't work as well.

By now, I am writing the rest all the test including always the first test('mylogin) but I am sure there is a way via pageObject

Regards

Answer (score 0):

demo_login.spec.js

```js
const {test, expect} = require('@playwright/test');

const auth_storage_path = 'storage_auth.json'; 
const {Login} = require('../../yourpathforfile/login_page.js'); 
const {Logout} = require("../../yourpathforfile/logout_page.js");

test('login_a', async ({page}) => {   
const login = new Login(page);   
await login.visit_baseurl();   
await login.method_login();   
await login.check_login_success();   
await login.saveAuth(auth_storage_path);   
await login.print_url_tenant();   
await login.print_browser(); 
});


test.describe("Login_a tests --> ", () => {

  test.use({storageState: auth_storage_path});

  test('demo_a test', async () => {
    expect( 1 +1).toBe(2);   });

  test('logout_a', async ({page}) => {
    const logout = new Logout(page);
    await logout.visit_baseurl();
    await logout.method_check_pageIsWorkplace();
    await logout.method_logout_workplace();
    await logout.method_check_logout();   
  });

});
```

objectPage-> login_page.js

```js
const { expect, firefox} = require('@playwright/test'); 
const uaParser= require("ua-parser-js");  


exports.Login = class Login {

 /**    
  * @param {import('@playwright/test').Page} page    
  */

  constructor(page) {
    this.page = page;   }

  async visit_baseurl () {
    await this.page.goto("/");
    //await this.page.goto(process.env.env_baseurl );   
 }

  async method_login() {
    const usernameId    = selectorUserId;
    const passwordId    = selectorPassId;
    const idLogin       = '[id="fc-login-button"]';
    const usernameValue = 'demo_user_123';
    const passwordValue = 'demo_pass_123';

    const mydelay = 200;
    await this.page.click(usernameId);
    await this.page.type(usernameId, usernameValue, {delay:mydelay});
    await this.page.click(passwordId);
    await this.page.type(passwordId, passwordValue, {delay:mydelay});
    await this.page.click(idLogin,{delay:mydelay})
  }

etc ....
}
```

the same for logout_page
If you need any more info just let mne know.